# Does Adoptium 17.0.2.8 have a JRE?

Tags: java, adoptopenjdk

Exactly what it sounds like. I've been looking for one, but all the replies say that the version does have a JRE, but I cannot find the folder for it. Is there even a JRE? If there is, can you please give an explanation? Thank you!

i.stack.imgur.com/R3mcT.png

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please post code, error messages, markup, and other textual information **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, that's the whole point of adoptium. OpenJDK has JRE binaries as you can see on [their website](https://adoptium.net/).

JRE is in bin/java.exe.

Comment: _"that's the whole point of Adoptium"_, it is not. The fact they provide a JRE download is not the raison d'etre of Adoptium.

Comment: my eclipse still doesnt recognize the jre in bin, even though i have seen the file myself.

Comment: eclipse doesn't use jre, it uses jdk. it probably also isn't installed, you need to give it where the file is stored.

Comment: im trying to add it through the search function since my current workspace jre isnt supported. still doesnt recognize.